# PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission's effect on auto-update

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am about to add the PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission to my app. Since this is a special permission that the user needs to grant from a special settings page, I would not expect it to appear in the Google Play permission list when they install the app - and thus I expect it not to enforce manual update for my app.
Will it enforce manual update for my app?

On a more general note - how can I test this? I can do it with alpha/beta groups, but there has to be a better way.